# block 2 things on a site with tampermonkey

Tags: iframe, tampermonkey

I want to block 2 things on a site ([www.exemple.com](http://www.exemple.com)) with tampermonkey :

- all iframes on a site
- a div id="dodo"

I've tried this (to Id="dodo"), but it doesn't work
:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Kill dodo
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @match        https://www.exemple*
// @require  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// @grant    GM.getValue

// ==/UserScript==
//- The @grant directives are needed to restore the proper sandbox.
/* global $, waitForKeyElements */

waitForKeyElements ("[id='dodo']", killNode);

function killNode (jNode) {
    jNode.remove ();
}
```

And to the iframe I don't have idea.
Thank you for your help, and sorry for my bad english !

Answer (score 0):

A cardinal rule of web design is that there cannot be more than one element on any page with the same ID. IDs are intended to be unique on the page. Modern web design does not respect this and you must now plan for that.

Similarly, modern web pages can be complicated, being rendered in components, and it is now often necessary to be very specific with your CSS selectors used in the document.querySelector / documentGetElementBy... functions. A good understanding of DOM Traversal is required. See notes B and C at end of this answer.

Also, in our modern era elements are added to the page at various times -- even during initial page load there can be ajax queries and additional items added to the page after the document.ready / DOMContentLoaded events have fired. Again, just plan for that (by adding wait code before your hunter/killer code).

Try something like this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Kill dodo
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @match        https://www.example*
// @grant        none

(async function() {
    'use strict';
    const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
    let repeatF=0, maxrepeats=100;

    kill_the_dodo();
    kill_all_iframes();

    function kill_the_dodo(){
        //THIS selector might need to become more specific (See notes B, C)
        while ( !$('#dodo') ){
            await sleep(100);
        }
        await sleep(100);
        $('#dodo').remove();
        //Assuming only one #dodo element, no need to repeat
    };

    function kill_all_iframes(){
        //THIS selector might need to become more specific
        while ( !$('iframe') ){
            await sleep(100);
        }
        await sleep(100);
        $('iframe').remove();
        //OPTIONAL: repeat 100x
        repeatF++;
        if (repeatF < 100) setTimeout( () => {kill_all_iframes()},250);
    };
})();

function sleep(ms){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(()=>{
            resolve();
        },ms);
    })
}
```

Notes:

(a) The above code is vanilla javascript, not jQuery

(b) Use the console (F12) to experiment while you are building your CSS selectors to drill-down to the desired elements to remove (e.g. > `document.querySelector(' insert your CSS selectors one by one here ');`

(c) [Here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkDAW7hhEYU) that will help you understand how to use CSS selectors to drill-down through the DOM to find your specific element. Although this presenter is using python to demonstrate, you can do the exact same thing in javascript (substitute `document.querySelector( //CSS here )` where he has `r.html.find( //CSS here )`

Comment: Thank you for your well-argued reply.
I'll test it out and let you know.
Many thanks,

Comment: Hi @Grouik - how did that work out for you? Was this answer helpful?